# How set ID and use it dynamically in mvc 4 razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, attributes, click

I have html elements in `foreach`. I cannot declare ID name to those manually.
I used  `id='ProductSelect_@(item.Id)'` to set Id:

```
  foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     <a href="#" id='ProductSelect_@(item.Id)' class="select-link">Select this</a>
   }
```

But, now I need **.click()** function for eash `<a>` link to do my some operations. How write click function for dynamic ID's?
I checked this, but it does not work :

```
$("#ProductSelect_@(item.Id)").click(function () {

   //any operation

 });
```

**Edit:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select-link').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

            url = '@Url.Action("SelectThis", "Product")';
            var data = { id: '@Model.Id' };
            $.post(url, data, function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    alert("Thanks");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Problem occured...");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

This click() functions send request to controller iteration counts times. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: `$('a').click();` can do that. Actually your purpose is not clear. Why do you want to select only particular id to do the stuff?

Comment: For example, asume that, answer accept structure in http://stackoverflow.com. Idea I need is similar, to select any item from answer's list which line up dynamically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using attributes.

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     <a href="#" data-id='@item.Id' id='ProductSelect_@(item.Id)' class="select-link">Select this</a>
   }
```

then in JS...

```
$('.select-link').click(function()
{
 var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

That way you're wired to all similar links (e.g. `select-list`) without a separate handler function for each #id.

Comment: thanks for this, it works, but when I click any link, operations works many times, till foreach ends...

Comment: Check your output code (HTML).  You're probably wiring up the JS I posted each iteration through the loop.  With my code you only need to add that JS ONE TIME, i.e. after the loop, and then it will work for all links.

Comment: I edited my question. please see. output code is right. values of data-id line up 1, 2, 3.  id='ProductSelect_@(item.Id)' also works, but, request goes to controller many times (iteration counts)

Comment: This is not correct still.  you're not understanding me.  You are adding that script block once per loop.  View your source in the browser.  If you see that script block more than one time in the output HTML, then there's your problem.

Comment: Ok, of course it is my problem. I need to select only one item from that links, like accepting answer in http://stackoverflow.com. When I click any link, to send it's id to controller.

Comment: Yes and my code will help you do this. `var data = { id: id };` I don't think you're understanding the solution and how jquery events work, and I unfortunately don't think I can explain it to you here in comments.

Comment: Thanks, I understand you now. my javascript function was working many times, because, I was using it in iteration. Your answer is solution for this.